# Is it possible to get the sObject type in the flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I know I can get record id of current page in the flow. How do you get the `sObject` type of current page in flow?

Comment: I have used id starts with and hard coded it, but that won't work if you are building a new object in sandbox as id would change when you deploy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to get `sObject` type in a flow(i.e. only through configuration).

You will have to write a custom `Apex` class with `InvocableMethod` and return the `sObject` type to the flow back.

Here is a [blog](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/set-your-flows-free-use-the-same-flow-on-multiple-objects) which explains the process to be followed to get the `sObject` type using `apex` class

Answer (score 2):

This is possible without Apex, if you don't mind a bit of manual work upfront.

Each object has a specific prefix (see [here](https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-object-key-prefix-list/)) which can be incorporated into your Flow in various ways.

One option is to build these Object prefixes into a Custom Metadata Type (CMT) and then reference this CMT in the Flow using the Get Records Element. You would then loop over the CMT object to check your current RecordId against the table of prefixes.

Of course, you'll need to update the CMT if you have a need to reference new objects created after the CMT.

Answer (score 0):

check this code and put in a class, then call it from the flow

```
@InvocableMethod
public static List<String> getSObjectType(List<String> recordIds) {
    List<String> sObjectTypes = new List<String>();

    for(String recordId : recordIds) {
        try {
            
            SObjectType sObjType = ((SObject)Type.forName(recordId).newInstance()).getSObjectType();
            sObjectTypes.add(sObjType.getDescribe().getName());
        } catch(Exception e) {
            
            sObjectTypes.add('Error: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    return sObjectTypes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Id of the record, you can detect what sObject type you are dealing with in the Flow by checking for the Id's prefix. For example, if the first 3 digits in the Id are '006' then you know you are working with an opportunity record.